# Create a new table by Product_ID that has: total 5/4/3/2/1 star reviews

Tags: mysql

How can I create a new table by `Product_ID` that has total 5/4/3/2/1 star reviews by using MySQL? I tried to PIVOT the table but it didn't work. Here's my table:
[image]

Thanks!

[Ideal Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKa4d.png)

Comment: Sample Data and desired output will be very helpful to every question viewer.

Comment: I put a small part of my table, please click the my table link in question.

Comment: I attached ideal result as a link at the end

Comment: Pictures don't count

Comment: I can not attach another picture because I don't have enough reputation, sorry.